# Best way to pass config file during Docker build

Tags: docker, dockerfile

My application requires a license file to run.  I don't want to include this in the Docker image I'm going to distribute.  I was hoping users should be able to provide their license file by mounting it as a volume during Docker run.

What I'm after is a way to transiently provide a license file to the Docker during the build phase.  I can't mount volumes during this phase.

Is there a standard pattern for performing this kind of thing?

In short, I need to provide a dependent transient file during build, so that the build completes but that file isn't included in the final image.

Answer (score 3):

What you want is an image that when built doesn't include the license file. It needs to be added each time the container starts.

I can think of several ways of doing this, the most obvious is to look for a mounted volume of a fixed name containing the license file at startup, and if not found exit with a message.

This Dockerfile illustrates the idea

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

RUN echo "#!/bin/bash" >> /bin/startup.sh
RUN echo "if [ ! -e /license/license.txt ] " >> /bin/startup.sh
RUN echo "then " >> /bin/startup.sh
RUN echo "   echo 'missing license'" >> /bin/startup.sh
RUN echo "exit 1 " >> /bin/startup.sh
RUN echo "fi " >> /bin/startup.sh
RUN echo "top " >> /bin/startup.sh

RUN chmod +x /bin/startup.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/startup.sh"]
```

Running this without a license director will cause it to not start. 
Running with a license will run top forever.

```
> docker run -it test
missing license
> docker run -v `pwd`/license:/license -it test
[works]
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `Dockerfile`'s build step, you would have to copy in the transient file and then delete it. It's important that this is done in the same `RUN` command, otherwise the transient file might end up in a cached union FS...which would probably be against the licensing, if that's what said transient file is.

Something like this:

```
RUN curl url/to/transient_file -o /containter/path/to/transient_file \
 && your_build_steps \
 && rm -f /container/path/to/transient_file
```

Comment: thanks for the comment, I didn't know about the caching

Answer (score 0):

You could specify it in an [environment variable file](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-environment-variables-e-env-env-file)

Comment: This answer doesn't address how environment variables read from the file at startup should be turned into a file inside the running container.